# Usage of MP4box to editing HEIC/HEIF image

Tags: grid, mp4box, heif

I tried to edit heif image using MP4box.

As overview of MP4box, it can used for editing/packaging of HEIF image
To be exact, what I wish to do is to set ispe(Image spatial extent) of grid as 512x512.
(Input file doesn't have ispe of grid, only has ispe of image itself)

Below explanation is maybe about setting the grid size.

```
-add-derived-image (string)
create an image grid, overlay or identity item, with parameter syntax :type=(grid|iovl|iden)[:opt1:optN]
* image-grid-size=rxc: set the number of rows and columns of the grid
* image-overlay-offsets=h,v[,h,v]*: set the horizontal and vertical offsets of the images in the overlay
* image-overlay-color=r,g,b,a: set the canvas color of the overlay [0-65535]
- any other options from .I add-image can be used
```

However, I'm not good at using MP4box and cannot find any example of using that command.
Does anyone help to write correct command for editing heif file?

Answer (score 1):

GPAC contributor here. You can have a look at our testsuite for [examples](https://github.com/gpac/testsuite/blob/3444dabe40dba17d3883d3750b248ec953c34d5d/scripts/iff-grid.sh#L83). Please note that the preferred way to report issue is to use our [issue tracker](https://github.com/gpac/gpac/issues).